# What is the condition to have a schiff base precipitate for sulfonamides?

Tags: carbonyl-compounds, aldol-reaction

In the sulfonamides group we observe that some category (like *sulfanilamide*, *sulfamethizol*) gives products of condensation with carbonyl so a precipitate, whereas other category (like *sulfaguanine*, *sulfapyridine*) don't give a precipitate in reaction with carbonyl. Why is there that difference although these 2 categories have the amino-benzene substituent?